# Micronaut JDBC: using kotlin value classes as @Id

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, micronaut-data

Is it possible to use Kotlin value classes as `@Id` property?

**Entity:**

```kotlin
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.*

@JvmInline
value class UserId(val value: Int)

@MappedEntity("users")
data class User(
    @field:Id
    @field:GeneratedValue
    val id: Int = UserId(0),
    val name: String
)
```

**Repo:**

```kotlin
import io.micronaut.data.jdbc.annotation.JdbcRepository
import io.micronaut.data.model.query.builder.sql.Dialect
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository

// Repo
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
interface UsersRepo : CrudRepository<User, UserId>
```

Currently, during compilation I am getting the following error:

```
error: Unable to implement Repository method: UsersRepo.update(Object entity). No identity is present
```

AFAIK, it is not possible with *micronaut-data-jpa*, but what about *micronaut-data-jdbc*?

Comment: Not that I am aware, but would type aliases solve your problem? (i.e. `typealias UserId = String`)

Comment: @u-ways yeah, thanks, currently this is the only way I found to introduce strict typing. I came from Scala, so trying to project my requirements on Kotlin :)

Comment: Awesome, I have expended on type aliases just to make sure that's the alternative you want. Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware. However, you can achieve something "similar" (readability-wise) using type aliases:

> Type aliases provide alternative names for existing types. If the type name is too long you can introduce a different shorter name and use the new one instead.

```kotlin
typealias UserId = String
```

So the above would become:

```kotlin
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.*

typealias UserId = Int

@MappedEntity("users")
data class User(
    @field:Id
    @field:GeneratedValue
    val id: UserId = 0,
    val name: String
)
```

However, do note that *Type aliases do not introduce new types*. They are equivalent to the corresponding
underlying types.

For example, when you add `typealias Predicate<T>` and use `Predicate<Int>` in your code, the Kotlin
compiler always expands it to `(Int) -> Boolean`. Thus you can pass a variable of your type whenever a general
function type is required and vice versa:

```kotlin
typealias Predicate<T> = (T) -> Boolean

fun applyTo42(predicate: Predicate<Int>): Boolean = predicate(42)

fun main() {
    val function: (Int) -> Boolean = { it > 0 }
    val predicate: Predicate<Int>  = { it > 0 }

    println(applyTo42(function))  // => "true"
    println(applyTo42(predicate)) // => "true"
}
```

Reference: [Kotlin - Type aliases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-aliases.html)

Comment: Thank you, @u-ways, but _typealias_ brings nothing more than better readability but I would like to also get compile-type checking (strict typing, as I did in Scala: `case class Id(value: Int)` or `opaque type Id = Int // Scala 3`